# multiple payment options with split payment in prestashop

Tags: prestashop

I have using prestashop 1.5.4.1 version.

I need to configure multiple payment options with split payment.

Example :if the checkout total value is $2310( i have two methods )

1. customer can choose two credit card for payment ,cusomer can enter amount value
   one credit card - 1310
   another credit card - 1000

2.customer can choose credit card and COD

paid 2000 using credit card and remain 310 amount using COD

how to configure above concepts .  any payment module is available ?

Answer (score 0):

PrestaShop's database has been conceived to handle multiple payments (either payments in multiple installments or payments with different means), but not the front office.
You need to create a new payment method which implements the user interface, then in PaymentModule::validateOrder() add multiple calls to Order::addOrderPayment().
Not an easy task, but still can be done.